# ExceptionMessage: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a method that returns data from an EF model:

```
 public IEnumerable<CommentViewModel> GetPostComments(long postId, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {

        return (from cm in _db.Comments
                let pd = new PersianDate(cm.CDate)
                where cm.PostId == postId
                select new CommentViewModel()
                {
                    CommentDetails = new Comment()
                    { Id = cm.Id, CDate = cm.CDate, UserId = cm.UserId, IsActive = cm.IsActive, IsDelete = cm.IsDelete, PostId = cm.PostId, Text = cm.Text },
                    DateView = pd.ToPersian_Span()
                })
                .OrderByDescending(cm => cm.CommentDetails.CDate)
                .Skip(pageIndex)
                .Take(pageSize)
                .ToList();
    }
```

I'm getting the above message, but I can't work out how to circumvent the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the error state, you can only use parameterless constructor in LINQ to Entities.

You must change this part : `let pd = new PersianDate(cm.CDate)`.

Maybe you can retrieve in your CommentViewModel the raw cm.CDate then create a readonly property that return PersianDate ?

```
public class CommentViewModel()
{
    // I suppose CDate is a DateTime
    public DateTime CDate { get; set; }

    // If C# 6
    public PersianDate DateView => new PersianDate(CDate);
    // If < C#6
    public PersianDate DateView { get { return new PersianDate(CDate); } }
}
```

Then in your query :

```
public IEnumerable<CommentViewModel> GetPostComments(long postId, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{

    return (from cm in _db.Comments
            where cm.PostId == postId
            select new CommentViewModel()
            {
                CommentDetails = new Comment()
                { Id = cm.Id, CDate = cm.CDate, UserId = cm.UserId, IsActive = cm.IsActive, IsDelete = cm.IsDelete, PostId = cm.PostId, Text = cm.Text },
                CDate = cm.Date // Changed here
            })
            .OrderByDescending(cm => cm.CommentDetails.CDate)
            .Skip(pageIndex)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();
}
```